# do not capture before string

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of tokens to capture:

```
sweet (capture)
SWEETENED (capture)
not sweet (do not capture)
bitterly sweet (do not capture)
```

Right now, I wrote this regex expression but it does not fulfil my requirements:

```
 ^(?!not)^(?!bitterly)(sweet|SWEET|Sweet)(ed|ED)?
```

This expression does not capture any of the terms. What lookahead should I use to capture this?

P.S. I'm using Python for this

Comment: There are 2 or 3 ways. Are you extracting or replacing? [This is the first that comes to mind](https://regex101.com/r/FWrgIb/2), but IMHO not the best.

Comment: hey! i'm extracting :)

Comment: Then try `filter(None, re.findall(r'\b(?:bitterly|not)\s+sweet|\b(sweet\w*))', s, flags=re.I)`, see https://ideone.com/J3pocG

Comment: .. or [**`(?!.*\b(?:not|bitterly))(?i)sweet(?:ened)?`**](https://regex101.com/r/dB8i1f/1/) if the position of `not` and `bitterly` does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Approach 1: match and capture what you need and just match the rest

You may leverage the `re.findall` that only returns the capturing group values if the capturing groups are defined in the pattern. You just need to match what you want to ignore, and match and capture what you need to obtain. However, it will also return empty elements when the capturing group fails to match, that is why `filter(None, results)` will come handy.

Here is a [Python snippet](https://ideone.com/J3pocG):

```
import re
s = '''sweet (capture)
SWEETENED (capture)
not sweet (do not capture)
bitterly sweet (do not capture)'''
print(filter(None, re.findall(r'\b(?:bitterly|not)\s+sweet|\b(sweet\w*)\b', s, flags=re.I)))
# => ['sweet', 'SWEETENED']
```

Here,

- `\b(?:bitterly|not)\s+sweet` - matches whole words `bitterly` or `not` followed with 1+ whitespaces and `sweet` substring
- `|` - or
- `\b(sweet\w*)\b` - a whole word `sweet` with any other word chars after it (you may use your own pattern instead of `\w*`)
- `flags=re.I` - makes the pattern case insensitive.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FWrgIb/3) (green texts will only be kept thanks to the code).

## Approach 2: Lookbehinds that do not allow much control over the input

A couple of words about a negative lookbehind approach: I do not think it is good in this case since lookbehinds in Python `re` are fixed-width, and all alternatives in the lookbehind must be of the same width.

You might use

```
(?i)(?<!\bbitterly )(?<!\bnot )\bsweet\w*
```

(see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FWrgIb/2)), but it would fail if there are 2 or 3 spaces in between `bitterly` or `sweet`.

## Approach 3: Variable width lookbehind with PyPi regex module

Another interesting solution is using PyPi regex module where you can use variable width lookbehinds:

```
import regex
s='''sweet (capture)
SWEETENED (capture)
not sweet (do not capture)
bitterly sweet (do not capture)'''
rx = r'(?<!\b(?:bitterly|not)\s+)\bsweet\w*\b'
print(regex.findall(rx, s, flags=regex.I))
# => ['sweet', 'SWEETENED']
```

See the [Python demo on REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/MCTBA27718).

The whole word `sweet` (with any word chars at the end) is matched only if there is no `\b(?:bitterly|not)\s+` pattern before it.

Comment: If using the `regex` module you could as well add `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` as an example (though I can only upvote once :)

Comment: @Jan, I have been coding in .NET for some years, I am accustomed to lookbehinds more than to `(*SKIP)(*F)`. Maybe that is more efficient, but that is already "syntactic sugar" :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Wiktor's answer which mimicks `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` you might be getting along with a neg. lookahead:

```
(?!.*\b(?:not|bitterly))(?i)sweet(?:ened)?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dB8i1f/2/).

---

Disadvantage (maybe?): the position of `not` and `bitterly` is not taken into account, thus a sentence like

```
sweet and not sour
```

won't be matched. It's up to you to decide whether this is desired or not.